# Writing translation for DateDiff for postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a translation of this method for PgSQL

```html
public static class AppPgsqlSqlFunctions
{
    public static int DateDiff(string datePart, DateTime from, DateTime to) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

I want to translate it to something like

```html
SELECT ('2015-01-12'::date - '2015-01-01'::date) AS days;
```

I dont know how to express it in HasTranslation

```html
 modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(AppPgsqlSqlFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(AppPgsqlSqlFunctions.DateDiff))!).HasTranslation(x => ...);
```

Comment: Why do you need that? `(to - from).Days` has translation.

Comment: You want to reduce to something like `SELECT ('2015-01-12'::date - '2015-01-01'::date) AS days;`. Well reduce it to **exactly that**. In Postgres subtracting a data from another date gives an integer. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Note that DATEDIFF uses "boundary crossing".  So `datediff(day...` counts the number of "midnights" between two datetime values.